# Can I use a variadic template to represent a set of parmeters?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I'm trying to create a class that a user can add callback functions to which will then all be called when the fire() method of the object is called.  Since the callback function could potentially accept any set of parameters, I was thinking I could implement it as a variadic template.  However, I'm not sure what the syntax would be.  The below code gives me warnings about the `unexpanded paramater pack 'Params'`.   I'm just trying to specify the parameter list my callback function needs.  Is there a valid way to express this?

```
template <typename... Params>
class Observable
{
    std::vector<std::function<void (Params)>> _callbacks;
public:
    void addCallback(std::function<void (Params)> fn)
    {
        _callbacks.push_back(fn);
    }

    void fire(Params params)
    {
        for (auto c: _callbacks)
            c(params);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Observable<int, std::string> obs;

    obs.addCallback([](int size, std::string name){ });
    obs.fire(5, "hello");
}
```

Comment: You forgot the `...` everywhere that you refer to `Params` or `params`: https://onlinegdb.com/BJ5w19rQ_